# Why is this perl command giving unexpected results?

Tags: bash, perl, environment-variables

In my `.bashrc`, I have

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/util/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"; export PERL5LIB=$HOME/util/perl5:$PERL5LIB
```

if afterward I do

```
env | grep PERL5LIB
```

I see

```
PERL5LIB=/home/myUser/util/perl5:/home/myUser/perl5/lib/perl5:
```

Why is the second path not correct? I would expect

```
/home/myUser/util/perl5/lib/perl5
```

to be added to PERL5LIB, rather than

```
/home/myUser/perl5/lib/perl5
```

am I misunderstanding something about the perl command passed to `eval`? Th output of that command, run in the command line (rather than from `.bashrc`) is

```
$ perl -I$HOME/util/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib
Attempting to create directory /home/myUser/perl5
$
```

Comment: What's the output of `perl -I$HOME/util/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`?

Comment: The only thing you're adding to `PERL5LIB` is `$HOME/util/perl5` The part after that is whatever it previously had. Why do you think it should have `util` in it?

Comment: @Barmar but before running this line, I do 

`unset PERL5LIB` just to be sure. The result is the same

Comment: @pretzlstyle: That's not the output of the command I asked for.

Comment: @choroba it appears that it is. At least that is all that goes to stdout. Edited again

Comment: Sounds like it produces different output depending on whether stdout is a terminal or pipe. Show the output of `echo "$(perl -I$HOME/util/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"`

Comment: Check out https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you tell it otherwise, local::lib uses ~/perl5.

Change

```sh
perl -I$HOME/util/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib
```

to

```sh
perl -I$HOME/util/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/util/perl5
```

Comment: success! Thank you. The usage here is strange. the -I aregument does not inform the location of `lib`? I know nothing at all about perl though

Comment: It informs `perl` of where to search for modules, such as local::lib. It has nothing to do with local::lib or where local::lib will inform Perl to search for the "local lib". e.g. If you install local::lib in a directory Perl already searches, `perl -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/util/perl5` would be sufficient.